# Trying to install gcc+ in Git

Tags: command-line, bash, git, gcc, mingw

For Installing gcc+ in Git for the Windows bash environment I can't seem to find anywhere the proper order of which should I download first? And how I would go about setting up the PATH environment.

I've only ever set up a python environment, and recently new to Windows, the past 10 years or so I've only ever had a macOS set up.

I was told I need the MinGW for windows, and I thought i already had that configured when I downloaded GIT, but the terminal doesn't recognize any of the commands for gcc+ or provide a version set up for it.

So I assume I have to download it separately.
I wasn't sure if there is a specific order to use in setting up 
the gcc+ environment for GIT command line if I should
download MINGW for windows first and set it up, or GIT first.

And if so how i would go about providing the appropriate PATH to 
be able to run and compile programs inside the GIT CLI Bash

Any help is greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: @harrymc thank you for the link, will check it out